# CloudFront returning content from origin instead of cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

We are using **AWS CloudFront** to cache static content(video files storer in AWS S3).
In **Cache Behavior Settings** caching by headers, cookies and query string is disabled what should improve caching.

In the same time on **Popular objects** page I noticed that some video files are requested many times but only few requests are returned from cache. Almost all our customers have to use the same region.

Anyway according to https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/

> AWS CloudFront have 205 Edge Locations and 12 Regional Edge Caches.

**Questions:**

- How in that case file which was requested **867 times** in **2 day period** could be returned from cache **only 36 times**?
- How to improve caching performance?

[image]

[image]